# How to Crawl Multiple Websites to find common Words (BeautifulSoup,Requests,Python3)

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm wondering how to crawl multiple different websites using beautiful soup/requests without having to repeat my code over and over.

Here is my code right now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
Website1 = requests.get("http://www.nerdwallet.com/the-best-credit-cards")
soup = BeautifulSoup(Website1.content)
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
a = Counter([x.lower() for y in texts for x in y.split()])
b = (a.most_common())
makeaframe = pd.DataFrame(b)
makeaframe.columns = ['Words', 'Frequency']
print(makeaframe)
```

**What I am trying to do** is ideally crawl 5 different websites, find all of the individual words on these websites, find the frequency of each word on each website, ADD all the frequencies together for each particular word, then combine all of this data into one dataframe that can be exported using Pandas.

Hopefully the output would look like this

```
Word     Frequency
the       200
man       300
is        400
tired     300
```

My code can only do this for ONE website at a time right now and I'm trying to avoid repeating my code.

Now, I can do this manually by repeating my code over and over and crawling each individual website and then concatenating my results for each of these dataframes together but that seems very unpythonic.  I was wondering if anyone had a faster way or any advice?  Thank you!

Comment: Just turn your code into a function with input the url? Then you don't need to repeat the code.

Comment: ... and maybe add a [loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop and update a main Counter dict:

```
main_c = Counter() # keep all results here
urls = ["http://www.nerdwallet.com/the-best-credit-cards","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python"]
for url in urls:
    website = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    a = Counter([x.lower() for y in texts for x in y.split()])
    b = (a.most_common())
    main_c.update(b)
make_a_frame = pd.DataFrame(main_c.most_common())
make_a_frame.columns = ['Words', 'Frequency']
print(make_a_frame)
```

The `update` method unlike a normal `dict.update` adds to the values, it does not replace the values

On a style note, use lowercase for variable names and use underscore's  `make_a_frame`

Try:

```
comm = [[k,v] for k,v in main_c]
make_a_frame = pd.DataFrame(comm)
make_a_frame.columns = ['Words', 'Frequency']
print(make_a_frame).sort("Frequency",ascending=False)
```

Comment: Hi Padraic,  while this code allows me to crawl multiple websites, it doesn't combine the data exactly how I need.  What I was hoping for was to add up all of the frequencies across the websites and to create two columns: Column A with the word, and Column B with all of the frequencies added together.  I have edited my Original Post to hopefully make it clearer.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: unfortunately, still the same problem

Comment: It works for me. It sorts the words from most frequent to least

Comment: Hi Padraic,  so the issue it seems with the edited code is that the values in the frequency column do not change regardless of how many URL's I put in.  It seems like it is only scraping the first page?  Is this happening for you?

Comment: Found out the problem -- what was happening was that the code was scraping each page but instead of adding the data together, it was just creating duplicates for each word for each website            (i.e. the - 250, the - 400, the - 300).  From there, it was all a matter of grouping the data together to find the answer.  Thank you for your help!  I have edited the code above

Answer (score 2):

Make a function:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

cnt = Counter()
def GetData(url):
 Website1 = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(Website1.content)
 texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
 a = Counter([x.lower() for y in texts for x in y.split()])
 cnt.update(a.most_common())

websites = ['http://www.nerdwallet.com/the-best-credit-cards','http://www.other.com']
for url in websites:
 GetData(url)

makeaframe = pd.DataFrame(cnt.most_common())
makeaframe.columns = ['Words', 'Frequency']
print makeaframe
```

Comment: this is going to create a separate dataframe for each call, the OP wants to combine into one

Comment: Hi Vizjerei,  while this code allows me to crawl multiple websites, it doesn't combine the data exactly how I need.  What I was hoping for was to add up all of the frequencies across the websites and to create two columns: Column A with the word, and Column B with all of the frequencies added together.  I have edited my Original Post to hopefully make it clearer.  Thank you for your time!